# Active Directory and Single Sign-on

Tags: active-directory, single-sign-on

can someone tell me if there is any Microsoft product to be used with Active Direcotry in order to do Single Sign-on? Or is this allready a functionality that AD delivers?

I know there are external tools for this, but i would be interested if there is build-in support from Microsoft.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on where you plan to use Single Sign-On? (internal web apps, third-party sites/apps, etc.)

Comment: Linking from an intranet application to external intranet application like SAP etc.

Comment: If I recall, Active Directory Federation Services (AD FS) is a role made specifically for handling SSO.

Comment: Ok thanks. I will try to find something about this on google :)

Comment: From the [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/active-directory-federation-services)

Comment: thank you. Will read through